# Datagridview rows are 0 even though I have a datasource

Tags: c#, .net

I am programmatically creating a datagrid view and binding data to it.  For some reason the rows are empty.  Strange as it may seem but I do not want to display the Datagrid view just pass it into a class which extracts the data as Excel and CSV.

```
 this.DataGridView = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();

  System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();
            bindingSource.DataSource = DataSource;

  this.DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = autoGenerateColumns;
  this.DataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
  Int32 rowCount = this.DataGridView.Rows.Count; // 0!
```

Is there any way after creating the data source I can get the rows to populate?

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `autoGenerateColumns`?

Comment: I believe DataGridViews don't bind/contain any rows until they are actually rendered.

Comment: autogenerate is set to true

Comment: @paul.abbott.wa.us this is my worry! gutted

Comment: Drop the Dgv and use a proper Collection class.

Comment: Why are you using DataGridView if you don't need to display it?  Where is DataSource created (and populated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe DataGridViews don't bind/contain any rows until they are actually rendered.

@paul.abbott.wa.us is right.

You can move the code that count the rows in **DataGridView.DataBindingComplete** Event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you need a DataGridView without displaying it on the UI in the first place. There are couple of alternates I can suggest

1. Let go the DataGridView and use DataTable/IEnumerable to keep the data. Both can provide you with 
   counts.
2. If you insist on keeping the DataGridView then something like

(Assuming its bound to a DataSet)

```
((DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource).Tables[0].Rows.Count
```

would also work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see data grid, you should add it to parent controls collection:

```
DataGridView = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
Controls.Add(DataGridView);
```

Currently your grid do not have any parent and cannot be displayed.